# how to do Spring filter in oneToMany

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity with a collection of comments. Now I want to add a field "private" to it. Comments with private=true should not be included unless explicitly asked for. I can obviously just create a dto which filters the entities. Is it possible to add a filter on the model which can conditionally be turned on or off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define a filter on the model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="comments")
@FilterDef(name="commentFilter", parameters={
    @ParamDef(name="private", type="boolean")
})
@Filters({
    @Filter(name="commentFilter", condition=":private=isprivate")
})
public class Comments {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="private")
    private boolean private;
    ...
```

and for query

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        System.out.println("--Enable Filter--");
        Filter filter = session.enableFilter("commentFilter");
        filter.setParameter("private",true);
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Comments> results = session.createQuery("from Comments").list();
```

Comment: Just make sure to replace the property name with a name that is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: @M-Razavi Thanks for your response. Would that still be possible if the main entity, say Post, contains an embedded collection of Comment?

Comment: @Anders yes, take look on this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511037/601288